# SAPUI5 events and constants list

Tags: sapui5

Where I can find all SAPUI5 internal (core level, like init event (sap.ui.getCore().attachInit method)) events ids or names to attach my custom handlers to them? I searched through documentation but wont able to find something useful. Is something like this even exist?

Comment: I think that sapui5 core is initialised before any of your conventional code (e.g. component or controller) is executed. It should be inside bootstrap. You can just add your own script into index.html. However, be aware that it won't work in Fiori launchpad context

Answer (score 1):

Method sap.ui.getCore() returns an instance of class sap.ui.core.Core. This class is documented here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html

The list of methods on that page include the methods that allow you to attach custom methods to the core. These methods all start with "attach".